# Alternate Blank Page on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have made a change to a Subreport on SSRS. The subreport should display on the last page of the whole report.

However when running this report as a PDF, a blank page is generated on every alternate page.

The margins and page size have not changed.

Answer (score 2):

What is most likely happening is that part of your report is too wide, and the extra space is printing on the second page. It's usually the report body (it can change as you add columns to your tables) - I would check that first. Just look at the properties and make sure the width isn't wider than what will print on your page.

If you're having trouble identifying which section the extra width is coming from, try changing the background colors on the header, body and footer sections. Set each of them to a different color, then print the report to pdf. You’ll see the colors in the pdf and be able to identify which one is too wide.

Also, make sure you add the margins into your total width as well. If you have .5" margins and can only print 8.5" wide, then your report can't be wider than 7.5"

Comment: This solution was essential for me to find out why every other page in PDF format was showing a blank. Trying to move tons of old Access-based reports onto SSRS for our business. Thank you so much for the color-background tip, it was a life-saver!